# Sensitivity of Newton's method initial vlaue

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

Can someone explain to me what sensitivty refers to when it comes to root finding?

When we say it is sensitive to initial value for x, is because there are multiple roots, or because there might be a critical point nearby or what? I hade a trigonometric function where the minimi point was under x-axis, then it was very sensistive and would converge to the other one etc. It is the orange graph in the picture below and I want it to converge to the last root which is around 4.5.

Then when we lifted the function up a bit, and thus the last root has changed to being on the maxima which is around 2. Here I feel like even when I get a little far away, it still converges to 2 unlike the first one. Anyways is this what they are referring to when in the question they said to study and compare the sensitivty of the initial value for x?

[image]

Comment: It can mean different things, you need to elaborate slightly. The behaviour of Newton's method is very dependent on initial conditions, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal for example (this is complex, but illustrates the point). It can also refer to sensitivity to the function data, for example $x \mapsto x^2$ has a root at zero but the slightly perturbed function $x \mapsto x^2+\epsilon$ has no root for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: One more thing I just realised that it took 19 iterations to converge for the red graph whilst it only took 7 for the orange one. Also the red one doesn't seem to converge quadratically. What can it depend on, if you look at graph? The initial value for red is 2 and for orange is 4.3.

Comment: I read somewhere that if the f'(x) is o at the root then it will converge slower as in linearly. Is it true? But if f'(x) = 0 then Newton's method won't even be defined since we divide by the derivative it must be non zero.

Comment: If $f'$ is non zero at a root (and is continuous there) and you start close enough it will converge quadratically (up to some numeric limit). If $f'$ is zero at a root (and non zero nearby) it converges linearly (which is slow). But yes, it needs to be non zero at all iterates to be well defined.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can read more about that? Seems like all the websites I have been to only mention that but never why? Why does it converge linearly if the root is a maxima or a minima?

Comment: Also I found a site that said if f'(x) is 0 then it would either converge slower or fail to converge. I am lost. What decides that?

Answer (score 4):

The convergence of Newton's Method is sensitive to initial conditions (even if the initial point isn't obviously near a critical point) and can be difficult to predict. In many cases, applying the method to a function in the complex plane leads to intricate fractal regions of convergence for each zero. Pictured is the fractal for the polynomial $z^{3}-2z+2$ (red regions fail to converge to any zero)

[image]

Source: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal?useskin=vector#/media/File:Newton_z3-2z+2.png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal?useskin=vector#/media/File:Newton_z3-2z%202.png)

Comment: I read somewhere that if the f'(x) is o at the root then it will converge slower as in linearly. Is it true? But if f'(x) = 0 then Newton's method won't even be defined since we divide by the derivative it must be non zero. –

Comment: f'(x)=0 at root means the root has multiplicity. wikipedia has a note about that case. When that happens, you can still compute the iteration as long as the iteration does not land on the root. @Need_MathHelp